# Check user already available in db using sails.js

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I am registering a new user by checking it is already available. But for every user it shows "user is already available"

```
signup: function (req, res) {
        var username = req.param("username");
        var password = req.param("password");
        var status = false;
        console.log("user : " + username + " : " + password);
        Signup.find({username: username}).exec(function(err, usr){
            if (err) {
                var response = {status:status, error:"db error"};
                res.send(500, response);
            } else { 
              if (usr) {
                status = true;
                res.send(400, {error: "Username already Taken"});
              } 
              else {
                signup.create({username: username, password: password}).exec(function(error, user) {
                if (error) {
                    res.send(500, {error: "DB Error"});
                } else {
                    req.session.user = user;
                    res.send(user);
                }
            });
        }}
    });
  },
```

Comment: You should try the insertion and catch the error if it fails. Doing a lookup and then an insert is vulnerable to timing-window problems and it is also twice as inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
Signup.find({username: username}).exec(function(err, usr){
    // usr is an array
});
```

the result of find is a list with objects matching your query. The list either has items or no items. In both cases

```
if (usr) {}
```

will be true, because you basically just check whether usr is defined which it always is. So change it to

```
if (usr.length === 0) {
    // already exists
}
```

Or you change find to findOne.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your model it clear that the username must be unique. So use `findOne()` function. It's return only one record( object ).

```
signup: function(req, res) {
    var username = req.param("username");
    var password = req.param("password");
    var status = false;

    Signup.findOne({ username: username })
        .exec(function(err, usr) {
            if (err) {
                var response = { status: status, error: "db error" };
                return res.send(500, response);
            }
            if (usr) {
                //status = true; --> in this case you don't use 'status' so this assignment is unnecessary
                return res.send(400, { error: "Username already Taken" });
            } else {
                Signup.create({ username: username, password: password })
                    .exec(function(err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.send(500, { error: "DB Error" });
                        } else {
                            req.session.user = user;
                            res.send(user.username);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
}
```